# Prepositions used in comparisons

Tags: предлоги, сравнительный

I've seen the following set expressions:

- Она на ... лет моложе/старше меня.
- Это в ... раз меньше/больше.

Are the prepositions **на** and **в** interchangeable in these contexts? If not, is there any rule justifying the employment of **на** and **в** in the respective examples?

Or those prepositions are there just "because"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*на* is addition or subtraction (*на двадцать лет старше* means "twenty years older"), *в* is division or multiplication (*в два раза старше* means "two times as old").